# chown command result in user invalid error in google colab

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory, chown

I try to run code `!sudo chown -R jupyter:jupyter /home/jupyter/training-data-analyst` from https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/training-data-analyst/blob/master/courses/ai-for-finance/solution/aapl_regression_scikit_learn.ipynb in Google Colab jupyter notebook.

Although my account authenticated with authentication_user() method:

```
from google.colab import auth
auth.authenticate_user()
```

I receive the error:

> chown: invalid user: ‘jupyter:jupyter’

I appreciate if you let me know how can I solve the problem, with a little bit description about what exactly happens when I run this code. All I have understood is that `chown` let me change the user and/or group ownership of a given file.

When I run `!ls -la`  on jupyter cell(in current working directory of /content) the output is:

```
total 28
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 22 19:27 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 22 18:34 ..
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 22 18:47 .config
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Nov 22 19:27 .ipynb_checkpoints
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 13 17:33 sample_data
```

the same result for /home directory:

```
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 24  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root 4096 Nov 22 18:34 ..
```

I don't know even if I clone training-data-analyst folder from google github, the code work or not! cause it states the user is invalid!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is an error because the user jupyter does not exist.

You need to create it first with

```
!groupadd jupyter
!useradd -g jupyter jupyter
```